# Debugging WCF web service in Visual Studio 2012 skips sections of my code

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging, visual-studio-2012, iis

I have a WCF web service without any pages. In my solution, I have three (relevant) projects: Console, Service, and Service.Lib. Service.Lib is a class library project contained within my solution. I have cleaned and rebuilt my solution in the 'debug' configuration and published it to my local machine.

When I start the Console project in order to debug, calls the Service project and I can attach to the IIS process which allows me to step through code from the Service project. However, when the Service project calls the Service.Lib project,  visual studio completely skips over all code from Service.Lib. If Service.Lib calls back to Service, debugging resumes and I can again step through the code. While in a section of the code which I can debug, the call stack omits all code from Service.Lib as with the label `[External Code]` Any ideas? I'd really like to debug Service.Lib.

I have checked several other questions on this site but none of them have helped. I am building everything in debug, my web.config contains the correct debug="true" setting, and visual studio is running as administrator. Thank you!

Comment: Is service.lib another class library project in your solution? or just an imported DLL?

Comment: @TheRk The first one. I have all the code for it and it's right there next to the Service project in the solution explorer.

Comment: Have you selected the `Debug` configuration for publishing?

Comment: @stuartd I have not because we do transforms on config files depending on the configuration and I need to select a particular dev configuration. To me, that doesn't seem like the culprit since I can debug the Service project.

Comment: So in the build configuration for the dev configuration you use are the values all set to Debug?

Comment: If you are running debug when its set to build as release it likely is not generating the Symbols for that class (the pdb files) those are requires to trace through.

Comment: @stuartd I'm building in debug configuration and publishing using the dev.cloud publishing profile. I believe that answers your question but, if not, feel free to re-ask.

Comment: @TheRk I'm building everything in the debug configuration. I have checked the directory and .pdb files exist for the Service.Lib .dlls.

Comment: Very odd, Is the Service Lib unmanaged code? ( c++ )? If not then im afraid i dont know the answer.

Comment: @TheRk Nope, the solution is 100% managed C#. No problem if you don't know the answer, I'm stumped too.